# How to convert an XML string where each 'line' aggregates the name of a column and its value to an xmltable?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an XML in the where each element below the root is a line; each line consists of exactly one column name and its column value. How do I convert said XML into an XMLTable?

I have tried to construct an XMLTable from the path '/root/line' (see code below).

```sql
with myxml as
 (select '<root><line><column>X</column><value_of_column>1</value_of_column></line><line><column>Y</column><value_of_column>2</value_of_column></line></root>' xml
    from dual)
select * from xmltable('/root/line' passing (select xml from myxml) columns "Name" varchar2(255) path '/root/line/column', "Value" varchar2(255) path '/root/line/value_of_column');
```

I expect the output to be:

```
   Name | Value
   ------------
   X    | 1
   Y    | 2
```

But the actual output is an error message: ORA-19224: XPTY0004 - XQuery static type mismatch: expected - node()* got - xs:string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. It seems the main point here is to pass an XMLType when using the PASSING clause:

```sql
with myxml as
 (select '<root><line><column>X</column><value_of_column>1</value_of_column></line><line><column>Y</column><value_of_column>2</value_of_column></line></root>' xml
    from dual)
select *
  from xmltable('/root/line' passing xmltype((select xml from myxml)) columns "Name" varchar2(255) path 'column',
                "Value" varchar2(255) path 'value_of_column');
```